# For my bash script I need for the input to be ~2 numbers

Tags: bash

For my bash script I need for the input to be 2 numbers.
I have already figured out how not to allow letters and >2 numbers.
Issue I have is, I need the input to be 2 numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p  "Enter Two Numbers " number
input=$number
re='^[0-9]{,2}$'
if [[ $number =~ $re ]]; then
      echo "'$input'"
   else
      echo "'$input' Please Enter Two Numbers"
fi
```

Comment: Remove the comma.

Comment: Try `'^[0-9]+ +[0-9]+$'`. If you remove the comma in your original re, then you'll allow for only one two digit number. My suggestion will allow varying amounts of whitespace.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek - Thanks. That is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

Two input exactly two values and require each to be an integer value, you can use a simple equality test, e.g.

```
read -r n1 n2 stuff
[ "$n1" -eq "$n1" 2>/dev/null ] && [ "$n2" -eq "$n2" 2>/dev/null ] && break
```

Testing whether a variable is numerically equal to itself is only satisfied if the variable holds an integer value. Redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` just hides the error when a non-integer or empty value is provided.

A short test script could be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## loop continually until valid input
while :; do
  printf "\nenter two numbers: "
  read -r n1 n2 stuff
  ## simple equality test for integer -- fails for non-integer values
  [ "$n1" -eq "$n1" 2>/dev/null ] && [ "$n2" -eq "$n2" 2>/dev/null ] && break
  printf "  error: '%s' and '%s' not two numbers\n" "$n1" "$n2" >&2
done

printf "two numbers: '%d' and '%d'\n" "$n1" "$n2"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/utl/read2numbers.sh

enter two numbers:
  error: '' and '' not two numbers

enter two numbers: a 4
  error: 'a' and '4' not two numbers

enter two numbers: 4 a
  error: '4' and 'a' not two numbers

enter two numbers: 1 20
two numbers: '1' and '20'
```

While you can use a Regex and use the bash `=~`, that won't be portable to POSIX shells. If you are just targeting bash, that's fine. Additionally, rather than craft a regex to validate two numbers in a single comparison, simply provide two conditional expressions and check each number separately -- it doesn't cost you anything in the grand scheme of things.

In bash using `[[ =~ REGEX ]]`, you can do:

```sh
  read -r n1 n2 stuff
  ## simple REGEX test for integer -- fails for non-integer values
  [[ $n1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && [[ $n2 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && break
```

Either way is fine. (same example use/output)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. If you must use a Regex -- just put the equality test in your hip-pocket for later.

Comment: @glennjackman -- right you are. Thanks. Guards needed. Fixed.